# Splitting a string by space in C

Tags: c, string

I'm working with C and through a socket I will be receiving a message with one space in it, I need to split the string into parts at the space. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I answered this question in another post [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22118068/3368887

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[strtok_r](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strtok_r.3.asp) is your friend.

Don't use plain `strtok()`, as it's NOT thread-safe.

Even on platforms where it is thread-safe (because the state is held in Thread-Local Storage), there is still the problem that the use of internal state means you cannot parse tokens from several strings simultaneously.

for example, if you write a function which uses `strtok()` to separate string A, your function cannot be called within the loop of a second function which is using `strtok()` to split string B.

Comment: This may be the case on some platforms but is not the case with MSVC.  strtok is thread-safe, as are the various other CRT functions which have traditionally used static storage.

Comment: @Will - updated. If I have it right, its use of TLS still means you can't be simultaneously strtokking two strings...

Answer (score 6):

If you own the string buffer, and know that it is safe to modify, you can use `strtok_r()` as people have suggested. Or you could do it yourself, like this:

```
char buffer[2048];
char *sp;

/* read packet into buffer here, omitted */

/* now find that space. */
sp = strchr(buffer, ' ');
if(sp != NULL)
{
  /* 0-terminate the first part, by replacing the space with a '\0'. */
  *sp++ = '\0';
  /* at this point we have the first part in 'buffer', the second at 'sp'.
}
```

This might be faster and/or easier to understand, depending on context.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done using the [strtok](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strtok.html)() library call.  Be warned, however, that this function will modify the input string (it inserts '\0' NUL characters everywhere that the chosen delimiter was found) - so you may want to call strtok() on a copy of the string if you need to access the whole thing later.

EDIT: as mentioned by another poster, "plain" strtok() isn't thread-safe, so strtok_r() is the safer function to call.  I'm not sure whether strtok_r() has the same problem of modifying the input buffer in-place.

Comment: strtok_r is, however a Posix function. it may not be available on windows.

Comment: Microsoft strtok *is* thread safe and has been for as long as I can remember.  The 'static' data is actually held in thread-local storage.

Comment: strtok() on MS may be thread-safe, but it is not re-entrant; only one bit of code may use it at a time.  That is, you cannot have FunctionA() using strtok() to parse a string, and have it call FunctionB() where FunctionB() also calls strtok() to parse a different string.  FunctionA() is now screwed!