# Splitting input lines at a comma

Tags: c, string, input, split

I am reading the contents of a file into a 2D array. The file is of the type:

```
FirstName,Surname
FirstName,Surname
```

etc. This is a homework exercise, and we can assume that everyone has a first name and a surname.

How would I go about splitting the line using the comma so that in a 2D array it would look like this:

```
char name[100][2];
```

with

```
       Column1     Column2
Row 0  FirstName   Surname
Row 1  FirstName   Surname
```

I am really struggling with this and couldn't find any help that I could understand.

Comment: I hope this is homework, because not everyone has a first name and a surname.

Comment: And if this isn't homework, why not use a scripting language?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting a string by space in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323285/splitting-a-string-by-space-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `strtok` to tokenize your string based on a delimiter, and then `strcpy` the pointer to the token returned into your `name` array.

Alternatively, you could use `strchr` to find the location of the comma, and then use `memcpy` to copy the parts of the string before and after this point into your `name` array. This way will also preserve your initial string and not mangle it the way `strtok` would. It'll also be more thread-safe than using `strtok`.

*Note:* a thread-safe alternative to `strtok` is `strtok_r`, however that's declared as part of the POSIX standard. If that function's not available to you there may be a similar one defined for your environment.

**EDIT:** Another way is by using `sscanf`, however you won't be able to use the `%s` format specifier for the first string, you'd instead have to use a specifier with a set of characters to not match against (`','`). Since it's homework (and really simply) I'll let you figure that out.

**EDIT2:** Also, your array should be `char name[2][100]` for an array of two strings, each of 100 `char`s in size. Otherwise, with the way you have it, you'll have an array of 100 strings, each of 2 `char`s in size.